# Why my observableArray is not working?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi I'm trying to do a foreach using a observableArray and I'm getting:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: Nome is not defined;
Bindings value: text: Nome
```

Here's my HTML:

```
<table data-bind="foreach: funcionarios">
    <tr>
        <p>Nome: <span data-bind="text: Nome"></span></p>
        <p>Apelido: <span data-bind="text: Apelido"></span></p>
        <p>Hobby: <span data-bind="text: Hobby"></span></p>
        <p>Função: <span data-bind="text: Funcao"></span></p>
        <p>Ramal: <span data-bind="text: Ramal"></span></p>
        <p>Email: <span data-bind="text: Email"></span></p>
        <p>Celular: <span data-bind="text: Celular"></span></p>
        <p>Aniversário: <span data-bind="text: Aniversario"></span></p>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's my Js:

```
var FuncionarioViewModel = function () {
    var me = this;

    function Funcionario(base, id, nome, apelido, hobby, funcao, ramal, email, celular, aniversario) {
        var me = this;

        me.Id = id;
        me.Nome = ko.observable(nome);
        me.Apelido = ko.observable(apelido);
        me.Hobby = ko.observable(hobby);
        me.Funcao = ko.observable(funcao);
        me.Ramal = ko.observable(ramal);
        me.Email = ko.observable(email);
        me.Celular = ko.observable(celular);
        me.Aniversario = ko.observable(aniversario);
    };

    me.funcionarios = ko.observableArray([]);

    me.add = function (id, nome, apelido, hobby, funcao, ramal, email, celular, aniversario) {
       me.funcionarios.push(new Funcionario(me, id, nome, apelido, hobby, funcao, ramal, email, celular, aniversario));
    };
}

var viewModel = new FuncionarioViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

And here's the Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqeb/8/

I'm not want to load page with default data in that array.

Comment: The fiddle goes to a different example?

Comment: @peacemaker sorry, I fix the link...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Ok, just checked your jsfiddle.  I updated to use the `if` binding to check if the array contains any elements before trying the `foreach` which will stop the binding error:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqeb/6/

I wrapped your `foreach` with the following:

```
<div data-bind="if: funcionarios().length > 0">
```

EDIT2:

Also, you've applied the `foreach` to the table tag which won't work.  I changed it to use the tbody tag instead and that works fine here:  http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqeb/10/

The changes look like this:

```
<div data-bind="text: funcionarios().length"></div>
<div data-bind="if: funcionarios().length > 0">
<table>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: funcionarios">
    <tr>
        <td>Nome: <span data-bind="text: Nome"></span></td>
        <td>Nome: <span data-bind="text: Apelido"></span></td>
        <!-- and so on... -->
    </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: but when I after add a item is list using: viewModel.add(1, 'Acaz Souza Pereira', 'Acaz', 'Ler', '.Net', '8756', 'acaz.souza@sapien.com.br', '(31) 8706-4103', '19/11/1988'); don't work. chekcout this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lrqeb/8/

Comment: it works? where? the register don't appear in the list 'funcionarios'. nothing happens

Comment: thanks man! the problem is because i'm using <P> instead a <TD>? Knockout.js fail when the html is not standard?

Comment: The issue was you had the `foreach` on the <table> tag which isn't iterable by knockout.  Glad I could help :)

Comment: no no, i put the foreach in <table> and still works. stop works when i use another html instead of <td>.

Comment: Looks like you need standard/valid html for it then!  Good to know

Comment: I asked the author of knockout.js about that and his answer: "browsers move badly nested elems out of table. Then KO hits them to bind in the wrong spot. Out of KO’s control. Browser thing."

Comment: Ahh interesting!  Thanks for sharing